# GL render does not show because of the QPainter

Tags: qt, opengl, qpainter

When I create a QPainter object in `paintGL()` function the rendered scene does not shown. Here is my code:

```
void D3Display::paintGL(){
  makeCurrent();
  glLoadIdentity();
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  // some adjustment stuff here...
  glPushMatrix();
  // some rendering stuff here...
  glPopMatrix();

  QPainter painter(this);
  // some overpainting stuff here...
}
```

Now the problem is: when I create the QPainter object, screen suddenly turns into black and does not show anything (including render and overpaint stuff). As you can see, I want to overpaint something on a QGLWidget , I am trying some stuff but I couldn't work it out. This function has been written similarly with the QT Overlay example project.

Comment: Try wrapping `QPainter` calls in `painter.begin(this)` and `painter.end(this)`, check the return value of `begin()`

Comment: Try setting `setAutoFillBackground(false)`

Comment: IIRC `QPainter` used to clear the background before it does its rendering, so that flag from above should deal with that, but if `begin()` returns false, it means there is another problem there.

Comment: I think you should be doing it the other way. 1. Initialize the painter. 2. `painter.beginNativePainting()`. 3. Do the openGL work. 4. `painter.endNativePainting()`. 5. Do the painter overpainting.

Comment: @KubaOber I tried it and it was kinda success. But now I cant do relocating on Z axis and the origin translated to upper left corner instead of middle.

Comment: You can translate wherever you want, and what Z order are you talking about?

Comment: @KubaOber I mean when I increase or decrease the translatef function's 3rd parameter nothing is changing in the render. Translation on X and Y axis' is working perfect but there is no working translation on Z axis.

Comment: Interesting. I might need to prototype it and see why it fails. Could you add the openGL code that you're using to draw something simple to your question? That way I could be sure I'm in the same scenario as you are.

Comment: Also, are you referring to the Z position of your 3D scene items, or of the 2D overlay painted by the painter?